# What Other Parameters Can I Try to Further Compress This PNG Image?

Tags: png, zlib

I wrote a program to losslessly recompress PNG files.  Since unfortunately there's no single parameter that guarantees doing this optimally, I just check all of them (compute time is no object, and anyway isn't unreasonable).

To be specific, there are:

- 10 levels of zlib compression to pass into `png_set_compression_level` (0 through 9)
- 5 zlib strategies to pass into `png_set_compression_strategy` (system, filtered, huffman only, RLE, and static huffman)
- Interlacing (2 values)
- A bunch of different prefilters to pass into `png_set_filter`.  I use `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` to check them all.

So my code basically compresses all possible (10*5*2 = 100) combinations and chooses the one with the lowest size.

This works excellently for a wide variety of typical images.  For some images, reductions can be up to 20% (although 5% is more typical).  For e.g. image-heavy websites, this is noticeable.

---

Here is a PNG image ([link to original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS2gm.png)):
[image: test image]

Here's a test image.  It takes up precisely 144,391 bytes.  My strategy's [best effort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyHmV.png) is 145,501 bytes.

I'm concerned not so much that this is 0.77% larger.  I'm concerned that *I checked all the parameters, and one of them should have been optimal*.  So this [Can't Happen](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/can-t-happen.html).

---

So my question: what's happening?  What parameters am I missing trying?  I didn't see anything else in the documentation.

Comment: Why can't it happen? You don't know if your original image was compressed with the exact same software you are using.

Comment: @pvg actually, I happen to know that the zlib and libpng versions the saving program uses are the same as the ones I'm using.

Comment: I suppose you can try one of the available free png optimizers and see what they come up with. If it's smaller, then it seems fairly reasonable to assume you're missing something in this wild goose chase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining the source of [OptiPNG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/optipng/), I discovered that:

1. The zlib memory usage parameter (passed indirectly from `png_set_compression_mem_level`) also affects the compression ratio.  This, despite what the [documentation](http://www.ludism.org/%7Erwhe/LSB/png/libpng-png-set-compression-mem-level-1.html) says.  I have no explanation for this, and think it's a Bad Thing.

   When I set this to `8` (the default) instead of the `9` I was using, I was able to reproduce the original image.
2. The filter parameter (to `png_set_filter`) makes a difference.  This sortof makes sense; choosing the optimal filter for a particular row doesn't necessarily mean a globally optimal compression (since that row might compress less-well with neighboring rows).  This is a complete guess, since none of this appears in the documentation.

   When I optimize over these values, I get a 140,541 byte image, which appears to be optimal.

Comment: Quality? That would have to be a bug. PNG compression is lossless.

Comment: @MarkAdler In the context of (especially lossless) compression, the _quality_ refers to the ability of the algorithm to get a high compression ratio. The _lossiness_ refers to the information loss. But this was definitely unclear; I have edited.

Comment: Ah, ok. The linked documentation doesn't say that the memory level _won't_ affect the compression level. I don't know what you mean by "it's a Bad Thing".

Comment: "pngcrush -zmem 6 -brute" writes a 140113-byte PNG file.  Pngcrush doesn't explore the zmem parameter by default because although there is sometimes a payoff, it's generally too small to be worth increasing the pngcrush run time by a multiple.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [recompressing with zopfli](https://code.google.com/r/ehoeks-zopfli-png/) to get some gain over zlib's best compression.